# Convert C# lambda query to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I was hoping to get some help in converting the following query to a SQL Server stored procedure.

```cs
    string[] Includes = new string[] { "IntakeData" };

    var r = _repo.Filter<ResultData>
                  (a => (a.TrackingIdentifier == trackingNum || 
                         a.IntakeData.Requestor_CaseID == trackingNum) 
                        && a.ResponseType == "RESPONSE"
                        && a.Status == "OK" 
                        && a.Destination == rs, Includes)
                      .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreatedDate)
                      .Select(c => new { c.ResultStatus, c.Destination, c.IntakeData })
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Below is the query I extracted from SQL profiler, but the SQL query generated is far too complex and many unnecessary null checks are generated as a result. So, we made the decision to simplify it by using a similar stored procedure.

```sql
    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[ResultStatus] AS [ResultStatus], 
    [Project1].[Destination] AS [Destination], 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[TrackingIdentifier] AS [TrackingIdentifier], 
    [Project1].[ClientTrackingIdentifier] AS [ClientTrackingIdentifier], 
    [Project1].[RequestorEmail] AS [RequestorEmail], 
    [Project1].[CandidateEmail] AS [CandidateEmail], 
    [Project1].[ConsumerIdentifier] AS [ConsumerIdentifier], 
    [Project1].[LocationIdentifier] AS [LocationIdentifier], 
    [Project1].[CandidateID] AS [CandidateID], 
    [Project1].[TotalCount] AS [TotalCount], 
    [Project1].[KitIdentifier] AS [KitIdentifier], 
    [Project1].[QueryStatus] AS [QueryStatus], 
    [Project1].[QueryData] AS [QueryData], 
    [Project1].[CreatedDate1] AS [CreatedDate], 
    [Project1].[CorporateEntityID] AS [CorporateEntityID], 
    [Project1].[Requestor_CaseID] AS [Requestor_CaseID], 
    [Project1].[CandidateSMS] AS [CandidateSMS], 
    [Project1].[NotificationType] AS [NotificationType], 
    [Project1].[REDTAILOrderCreationStatus] AS [REDTAILOrderCreationStatus], 
    [Project1].[REDTAILOrderCreationErrorMessage] AS [REDTAILOrderCreationErrorMessage], 
    [Project1].[APIInviteData] AS [APIInviteData], 
    [Project1].[CRN] AS [CRN]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Filter1].[ResultStatus] AS [ResultStatus], 
        [Filter1].[Destination] AS [Destination], 
        [Filter1].[CreatedDate1] AS [CreatedDate], 
        [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent3].[TrackingIdentifier] AS [TrackingIdentifier], 
        [Extent3].[ClientTrackingIdentifier] AS [ClientTrackingIdentifier], 
        [Extent3].[RequestorEmail] AS [RequestorEmail], 
        [Extent3].[CandidateEmail] AS [CandidateEmail], 
        [Extent3].[ConsumerIdentifier] AS [ConsumerIdentifier], 
        [Extent3].[LocationIdentifier] AS [LocationIdentifier], 
        [Extent3].[CandidateID] AS [CandidateID], 
        [Extent3].[TotalCount] AS [TotalCount], 
        [Extent3].[KitIdentifier] AS [KitIdentifier], 
        [Extent3].[QueryStatus] AS [QueryStatus], 
        [Extent3].[QueryData] AS [QueryData], 
        [Extent3].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate1], 
        [Extent3].[CorporateEntityID] AS [CorporateEntityID], 
        [Extent3].[Requestor_CaseID] AS [Requestor_CaseID], 
        [Extent3].[CandidateSMS] AS [CandidateSMS], 
        [Extent3].[NotificationType] AS [NotificationType], 
        [Extent3].[REDTAILOrderCreationStatus] AS [REDTAILOrderCreationStatus], 
        [Extent3].[REDTAILOrderCreationErrorMessage] AS [REDTAILOrderCreationErrorMessage], 
        [Extent3].[APIInviteData] AS [APIInviteData], 
        [Extent3].[CRN] AS [CRN], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[IntakeDataID] AS [IntakeDataID], [Extent1].[TrackingIdentifier] AS [TrackingIdentifier1], [Extent1].[ResultStatus] AS [ResultStatus], [Extent1].[Destination] AS [Destination], [Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate1], [Extent2].[Requestor_CaseID] AS [Requestor_CaseID]
            FROM  [dbo].[ResultData] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[IntakeData] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IntakeDataID] = [Extent2].[ID]
            WHERE (''RESPONSE'' = [Extent1].[ResponseType]) AND ([Extent1].[ResponseType] IS NOT NULL) AND (''OK'' = [Extent1].[Status]) AND ([Extent1].[Status] IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Filter1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[IntakeData] AS [Extent3] ON [Filter1].[IntakeDataID] = [Extent3].[ID]
        WHERE ((([Filter1].[TrackingIdentifier1] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Filter1].[TrackingIdentifier1] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Filter1].[TrackingIdentifier1] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)) OR (([Filter1].[Requestor_CaseID] = @p__linq__1) AND ( NOT ([Filter1].[Requestor_CaseID] IS NULL OR @p__linq__1 IS NULL))) OR (([Filter1].[Requestor_CaseID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))) AND ((([Filter1].[Destination] = @p__linq__2) AND ( NOT ([Filter1].[Destination] IS NULL OR @p__linq__2 IS NULL))) OR (([Filter1].[Destination] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL)))
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[CreatedDate] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000),@p__linq__1 varchar(8000),@p__linq__2 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='06ONMJ99SN',@p__linq__1='06ONMJ99SN',@p__linq__2='ACCIO'
```

Any help here to simplify the generated SQL query to a smaller stored procedure would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can enable logging if it is EF and inspect the query that EF generates for this linq query. Take it as a base and reuse during Stored Procedure/Function creation. Or you can read transactions/queries from database and track down this one and do the same. Without knowing which ORM and Database you have, types of your entities props we will not be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that.. added sql-server tag

Comment: The extra joins are to map included navigation properties. You need to think about whether you want those or not.

Comment: Read-only operations should be a `FUNCTION` or `VIEW` instead of a `PROCEDURE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try following procedure. The stored procedure simplifies the query and encapsulates it, making it more maintainable and reusable.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFilteredResultData
    @TrackingIdentifier NVARCHAR(8000),
    @Requestor_CaseID NVARCHAR(8000),
    @Destination NVARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
        rd.ResultStatus,
        rd.Destination,
        rd.ID,
        rd.TrackingIdentifier,
        rd.ClientTrackingIdentifier,
        rd.RequestorEmail,
        rd.CandidateEmail,
        rd.ConsumerIdentifier,
        rd.LocationIdentifier,
        rd.CandidateID,
        rd.TotalCount,
        rd.KitIdentifier,
        rd.QueryStatus,
        rd.QueryData,
        rd.CreatedDate AS CreatedDate1,
        rd.CorporateEntityID,
        rd.Requestor_CaseID,
        rd.CandidateSMS,
        rd.NotificationType,
        rd.REDTAILOrderCreationStatus,
        rd.REDTAILOrderCreationErrorMessage,
        rd.APIInviteData,
        rd.CRN
    FROM ResultData rd
    LEFT JOIN IntakeData id ON rd.IntakeDataID = id.ID
    WHERE (rd.TrackingIdentifier = @TrackingIdentifier OR id.Requestor_CaseID = @Requestor_CaseID)
        AND rd.ResponseType = 'RESPONSE'
        AND rd.Status = 'OK'
        AND rd.Destination = @Destination
    ORDER BY rd.CreatedDate DESC;
END
```

When you want to retrieve the data using this query, you can call the `GetFilteredResultData` stored procedure and pass the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a super fast reformat and removing aliases and a lot of unneeded parenthesis and square brackets and null checking and obviously NOT tested.

Still to do:

- Setup the parameters to call this
- Change the horrid parameter names
- Test both this cte version and a sub-select version as performance may vary

Kind of ugly code:

```sql
  CREATE PROCEDURE GetFilteredResults (
       @p__linq__0 varchar(8000) = '06ONMJ99SN',
       @p__linq__1 varchar(8000) = '06ONMJ99SN',
       @p__linq__2 varchar(8000) = 'ACCIO'
   ) AS
   BEGIN
       WITH cteFT AS (
           SELECT 
               RD.IntakeDataID,
               RD.TrackingIdentifier AS TrackingIdentifier1,
               RD.ResultStatus,
               RD.Destination,
               RD.CreatedDate AS CreatedDate1,
               ITD.Requestor_CaseID 
           FROM dbo.ResultData AS RD
           LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IntakeData AS ITD ON RD.IntakeDataID = ITD.ID
           WHERE 
               RD.ResponseType = 'RESPONSE'
               AND RD.[Status] = 'OK'
       ), cteP AS (
           SELECT 
               FT.ResultStatus ,
               FT.Destination ,
               FT.CreatedDate1 AS CreatedDate,
               ITD3.ID ,
               ITD3.TrackingIdentifier ,
               ITD3.ClientTrackingIdentifier ,
               ITD3.RequestorEmail A,
               ITD3.CandidateEmail ,
               ITD3.ConsumerIdentifier ,
               ITD3.LocationIdentifier,
               ITD3.CandidateID ,
               ITD3.TotalCount ,
               ITD3.KitIdentifier ,
               ITD3.QueryStatus ,
               ITD3.QueryData ,
               ITD3.CreatedDate AS CreatedDate1,
               ITD3.CorporateEntityID ,
               ITD3.Requestor_CaseID ,
               ITD3.CandidateSMS ,
               ITD3.NotificationType ,
               ITD3.REDTAILOrderCreationStatus,
               ITD3.REDTAILOrderCreationErrorMessage ,
               ITD3.APIInviteData ,
               ITD3.CRN,
               1 AS C1
           FROM cteFT AS FT
           LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IntakeData AS ITD3 ON FT.IntakeDataID = ITD3.ID
           WHERE 
               (( FT.TrackingIdentifier1 = @p__linq__0 AND FT.TrackingIdentifier1 IS NOT NULL )
                   OR ( FT.TrackingIdentifier1 IS NULL AND @p__linq__0 IS NULL )
                   OR ( FT.Requestor_CaseID = @p__linq__1 AND FT.Requestor_CaseID IS NOT NULL )
                   OR ( FT.Requestor_CaseID IS NULL AND @p__linq__1 IS NULL ) )
           AND (( FT.Destination IS NOT NULL AND FT.Destination = @p__linq__2 )
                   OR ( FT.Destination IS NULL AND @p__linq__2 IS NULL ) )
       )
       SELECT TOP (1)
           C1,
           ResultStatus,
           Destination,
           ID,
           TrackingIdentifier,
           ClientTrackingIdentifier,
           RequestorEmail,
           CandidateEmail,
           ConsumerIdentifier,
           LocationIdentifier,
           CandidateID,
           TotalCount,
           KitIdentifier,
           QueryStatus,
           QueryData,
           CreatedDate,
           CorporateEntityID,
           Requestor_CaseID,
           CandidateSMS,
           NotificationType,
           REDTAILOrderCreationStatus,
           REDTAILOrderCreationErrorMessage,
           APIInviteData,
           CRN
       FROM cteP
       ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC;
   END
```